# Restart a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm having an issue restarting the fragment in my Activity. When the user completes a round, I need the fragment that is implemented by the activity to completely restart. The fragment has an if / else statement that checks to see if a round has already been played, and if so, it needs to reload the fragment with alternative values. I've been looking all over and can't seem to find much of anything on this, so any help is much appreciated!

```
public class BoardActivity extends Activity implements BoardFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {

    public void gameTimer() {
    Timer t = new Timer();
    t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.RoundTimer);
                    tv.setText(String.valueOf(minutes) + ":" + String.valueOf(seconds) + ":" + String.valueOf(milliseconds));
                    milliseconds -= 1;

                    if (milliseconds == 0) {
                        tv.setText(String.valueOf(minutes) + ":" + String.valueOf(seconds) + ":" + String.valueOf(milliseconds));

                        milliseconds = 1000;
                        seconds = seconds - 1;
                    }

                    if (seconds == 0) {
                        timerout = "Out of Time!";
                        tv.setText(String.valueOf(timerout));
                    }

                    if (timerout == "Out of Time!") {
                        Model.gameCounter = Model.gameCounter + 1;
                        nextRound();
                    }

                }

            });
        }

    }, 0, 1);
}

private void nextRound(){

    //redirect to next round
    if (Model.gameCounter <= 1 && Model.gameCounter < 4) {
        Log.d(TAG,"new round");
        Fragment frg = null;
        frg = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("BoardFragment");
        final FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.detach(frg);
        ft.attach(frg);
        ft.commit();
    } else {
        //eventually add score screen
        Log.d(TAG,"same round");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation on attach and detach does say that the view hierarchy get destroyed and rebuilt. However, the state of the views is maintained, and so it should be expected to seem as if nothing has happened (which it sounds like what you are seeing). The docs say it is the same thing that happens when the fragment goes on the back stack.

Thus I think you have two options for "restarting" the fragment.

Option 1: Create a new fragment each time.

```
private void nextRound(){
    //redirect to next round
    if (Model.gameCounter <= 1 && Model.gameCounter < 4) {
        Log.d(TAG,"new round");
        Fragment frg = null;
        frg = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("BoardFragment");
        Fragment newfrg = new BoardFragment();
        final FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        if (frg == null) {
            ft.add(R.id.board_container, newfrg, "BoardFragment");
        } else {
            ft.replace(R.id.board_container, newfrg, "BoardFragment");
        }
        ft.commit();
    } else {
        //eventually add score screen
        Log.d(TAG,"same round");
    }

}
```

Option 2: Write a method in BoardFragment to reset the board for the next round, and call that when you are restarting.

```
private void nextRound(){
    //redirect to next round
    if (Model.gameCounter <= 1 && Model.gameCounter < 4) {
        Log.d(TAG,"new round");
        BoardFragment frg = (BoardFragment) 
            getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("BoardFragment");
        frg.restart();
    } else {
        //eventually add score screen
        Log.d(TAG,"same round");
    }

}
```